# Getting Streets of a specific postcode using Open Street Maps

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim, overpass-api

I want to write a code that has the Countrycode and Postcode as an input and the ouput are the streets that are in the given postcode using some apis that use GSM.

My tactic is as follows:

1. I need to get the relation Id of the district. For Example 1991416 is the relation id for the third district in Vienna - Austria. It's provided by the nominatim api:  http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=158947085
2. Put the id in this api url:  http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/get_wkt.py?id=1991416&params=0
3. After downloading the polygon I can put the gathered polygon in this query on the overpass api

   (
   way
   (poly: "polygone data")
   ["highway"~"^(primary|secondary|tertiary|residential)$"]
   ["name"];

   );
   out geom;

And this gives me the streets of the searched district. My two problems with this solution are 
1. that it takes quite a time, because asking three different APIs per request isn't that easy on ressources and 
2. I don't know how to gather the relation Id from step one automatically. When I enter a Nominatim query like http:// nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&country=austria&postalcode=1030 I just get various point in the district, but not the relation id of the searched district in order to get the desired polygone.

So my questions are if someone can tell my how I can get the relation_Id in order to do the mentioned workflow or if there is another, maybe better way to work this issue out.

#### Thank you for your help!

Best Regards 
Daniel

Comment: Did you tried an ordinary OSM geocoder as Nominatim? http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=18055

Comment: yeah of course, I also mentioned it in the text that using the link http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&country=austria&postalcode=1030 doesn'T help me anythink since I can't get the relation out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your approach quite a bit, down to a single Overpass API call, assuming you define some relevant tags to match the relation in question. In particular, you don't have to resort to using `poly` at all, i.e. there's no need to convert a relation to a list of lat/lon pairs. Nowadays the concept of an **area** can be used instead to query for certain objects in a polygon defined by a way or relation. Please check out the [documentation for more details on areas](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#By_area_.28area.29).

To get the matching area for relation 1991416, I have used postal_code=1030 and boundary=administrative as filter criteria. Using that area you can then search for ways in this specific polygon:

```c
//uncomment the following line, if you need csv output
//[out:csv(::id, ::type, name)];

//adjust area to your needs, filter critera are the same as for relations
area[postal_code=1030][boundary=administrative]->.a;

// Alternative:  {{geocodeArea:name}} -> see
// http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/Extended_Overpass_Queries

way(area.a)["highway"~"^(primary|secondary|tertiary|residential)$"]["name"];
(._;>;);out meta;

// just for checking if we're looking at the right area
rel(pivot.a);out geom;
```

Try it on overpass turbo link: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/6uN

Note: not all ways/relations have a corresponding area, i.e. some area generation rules apply (see wiki page above). For your particular use case you should be ok, however.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. I've read so much about the Overpass Api, but somehow overlooked the principe of an area. I'm definitely going to read up a bit on that concept.
I have an additional question:
When I simplify your query to this little query to http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/6uS
I only get the ways, which is fine because I only need the names of the streets. Is there any way to get the unique names of the streets since the ouput of the query isn't unique.
Thank you!

Comment: Oh and another question! You're using the post code only for identification of the area and it works fine, but as I know post codes arent unique in the world, so is there a possibility to do something like area[postal_code=1030][countrycode=AT][boundary=administrative]->.a; ?
Sadly I can't find any documentation for the input for area querys. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Regarding your 2nd question: this won't work that way, as countrycode=AT is not directly included in relation 1991416 as a tag. Unfortunately, I don't know if ref:at:gkz is used consistently in Austria. If so, you could just add ["ref:at:gkz"] as additional filter criterion. You might want to get in touch with the OpenStreetMap community in Austria on their tagging rules wrt  postal_codes. I'm not familiar with that detail. There's also some experimental support to query for areas in areas in Overpass API (see wiki page again for map_to_area examples).

Comment: Regarding your first question: like I mentioned in my code, you could use CSV as output format and just output the names. Note that you'll still have to sort this result and remove duplicates. Overpass API can't do that for you. http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/6uY

Comment: That's a great thing, thank you. The problem is that somehow this query only works with postcodes from vienna. When I for example enter a postcode in Berlin, Germany like 10115 there is no output. Do you know any query like this that would work for more postcodes?
Thanks again!

Comment: So in fact I need a solution for one or if better more queries in order to cover up most regions. I need pois and streets. Thank you!

Comment: In Germany, postal codes are modeled in a slightly different way, as boundary=postal_code, so if you replace the first line by `area[postal_code=10115][boundary=postal_code]->.a;` you'll get the result you want. 

I highly recommend to spend more time on the OSM data model and in particular tagging schemes used, as this is way beyond the scope of stackoverflow. 

The OSM wiki is a great starting point for this. Also try forum.openstreetmap.org for more insight or one of the OSM mailing lists (whichever you find more useful).

Comment: @wb9688: what do you mean by this comment? What have you tried, what doesn't work?

Comment: When I go to that Overpass link and replace the postal_code to e.g. '1104BA' I don't get any results.