# How to find all ways in an administrative area

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, overpass-api

I would like to find all the streets in a suburb. I can find the boundary of the suburb with a query like:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(
    relation["boundary"="administrative"]["name"="Crows Nest"](around: 250,-33.8255609,151.1992762);
);
out geom;
```

What I can't work out is how to use that as the bounding box / search area for streets (or if that should be possible). For example:

```
  way    (r)    ["highway"~"^(primary|secondary|tertiary|residential)$"];
```

Doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is basically covered by this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429376/getting-streets-of-a-specific-postcode-using-open-street-maps?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

By using an area, you can restrict the search for highway=* to a given administrative boundary:

```
area["boundary"="administrative"]["name"="Crows Nest"][wikidata="Q5189586"];
way(area)[highway];
out geom;
```

I'm using wikidata to make the area unique, because there's another area of that same name in the US.